# Pressing the power off button is registered in HP Active Health System logs?

Tags: hp, ilo, unexpected-shutdown

I have a customer which suffered an unexpected shutdown of one of his servers (Proliant DL320e Gen8 v2)

According logs inside the server it seems that someone pressed the power off button but the customer swears that is impossible.

I donwloaded logs inside ILO from Active Health System (AHS) but you need a valid maintenance contract and it is expired.

Before renewing the contract I would like to know if "pressing the power off button" like actions are registered in AHS logs.

Any HP employee here?

Comment: I made the same question in HP community forums and I get an afirmative answer.   https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Pressing-the-power-off-button-is-registered-in-HP-Active-Health/td-p/6966404

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer is yes.

I made the same question at HP community forums

https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Pressing-the-power-off-button-is-registered-in-HP-Active-Health/td-p/6966404

Someone pasted an screenshot and it seems that pressing the power button is registered in the log.